# Workaround for drawing bug when Overlaying a <div> over an <iframe> in Safari?

Tags: iframe, safari, rendering

I'm getting a very weird drawing bug in Safari, and i would like to see if there's any workaround I could take...

I'm currently displaying a <div> (absolutely positioned, high z-index) on top of an IFrame that displays contents from other sites. Just for context, the <div> is a toolbar we show over other sites.

This works well in all browsers, but in Safari, when the IFrame is showing **some** sites, and the user scrolls the page in the IFrame, the drawing of the toolbar gets all screwed up.

Here is a very minimalistic POC that reproduces the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mainContainer" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left:0; height: 500px; width: 500px; border: 2px solid red;">
    <div id="floatingToolbar" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 20px; height: 40px; width: 300px; background-color: blue; color: red; z-index:200;">
        Toolbar!
    </div>
    <iframe id="theIFrame" src="http://www.overstock.com/Clothing-Shoes/Skynyrd-Mens-Rock-Roll-Freebird-Lyric-T-shirt/3023049/product.html?sec_iid=33972" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left:0; height: 500px; width: 500px; border: 2px solid red;">
    </iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

If you save that to your hard drive, and open it with Firefox, you'll get this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [crystalgears.com](http://www.crystalgears.com/temp/safariproblem_firefox.jpg))</sub>

---

And if you open it in Safari, and wildly scroll up and down inside the IFrame, it'll look like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [crystalgears.com](http://www.crystalgears.com/temp/safariproblem_safari.jpg))</sub>

---

Now, this **only** happens in Safari. Chrome works correctly.
It happens in Safari Windows and Mac. I'm testing with Safari Windows 3.2.1 (525.27.1), but i've seen it happen in other versions.

To make this more mysterious, it only happens when I show **some** sites inside the IFrame. For example, if you show www.google.com or www.stackoverflow.com, the toolbar works perfectly. However, items inside www.overstock.com or www.amazon.com work well. Also, it's not only *a few* sites that give me this problem. It's **a lot**. I haven't been able to find some special thing that differentiates consistently the "bad" sites from the "good" ones, but I haven't looked deep enough. Maybe it's the DOCTYPE, or something else. What seems to be a rule (although it's admittedly very soft) is that "complex" or "heavy" sites tend to trigger it, while "light" sites don't.

Any ideas of what I could do to work around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh! Fun! It's been reported as a bug already :-( [https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25216](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25216)

Comment: For the record, I'm not seeing this in Safari 4 Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the unexpected when rendering on top of an iframe, similar to when a div is positioned over a flash video. It can work, and sometimes does. But scrolling or movement in the flash or iframe can trigger some rendering issues.

Is there any chance you could use a different solution then the iframe? Would using a library like cURL to get the data off a different page suffice?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
No, we can't get away without an IFrame, we want to let users use the other site inside ours. Proxying it through cURL will break most modern sites, since a lot of them depend on Javascript working for a lot of their functionality.
I agree that drawing over an IFrame is "weird". I didn't even expect the z-index to work when I first tried it, but in truth, all the other browsers behave PERFECTLY, even crappy IE6...

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on how many users use Safari vs How bad you want people to use this functionality. cURL can still work with JS.. loop through the external references and make them absolute paths. Of course, this method is not a good way either. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, that's a security disaster waiting to happen... :-)
Plus looping through the external references is an ideal-word solution. Lots of site include JS dynamically by doing weird Response.Write's, adding <script> elements, etc. But above all, it's a big security hole i'm not willing to try to close by myself (like Facebook does with their FBJS)

Comment: Isn't response.write part of ASP? cURL can only get what is outputted to the browser.