# Browser issue when embedding an iframe in absolute div

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, cross-domain

I'm encountering a strange issue when embedding an iframe with a particular src within an absolutely positioned div.
Here's the basic markup of the page:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: -400px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
}
iframe {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque commodo sit amet elit sed cursus. Fusce nibh nibh, venenatis consectetur hendrerit sed, aliquam sit amet eros. Sed sem augue, tristique ut odio sit amet, euismod bibendum nunc. Nullam ac ligula pharetra, ultrices lorem id, porttitor enim. Nullam sit amet sagittis erat.
    <div class="content">
        <iframe src="https://app-apac.thebookingbutton.com/properties/yaangcomedirect"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div `.container`covers the whole page; inside of it, there's a div `.content` absolutely positioned relative to `.content` div that should not be visible, hidden by the `right:-400px` property and its width, that's `300px`.

When the iframe loads, the whole page seems to be "slided" to the left. You can see this behaviour by the dummy text inserted, that's now cut, and the iframe, that's partially visible now.

This is shown when the iframe is still loading:
https://i.imgsafe.org/89a753d.jpg

When the iframe is loaded, this is shown:
https://i.imgsafe.org/8820624.jpg

I'm encountering this issue in Chrome, Firefox and Edge at their latest stable version, so I think that this could probably not be a browser issue.
I know for sure that other sources for the iframe work very well and doesn't show this issue.
Moreover, I'm aware that a cross-origin frame can't get to the document properties of the top frame, and this is probably the thing that makes this story very strange.

In addition, in developer console on Chrome or Firebug there's not any node that shows the style attribute (if some javascript could modify the original markup).
I'm sorry to say that I don't control the iframe content, this is cross-origin for most of the cases.

Could you tell me more about that? I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850484/workaround-for-drawing-bug-when-overlaying-a-div-over-an-iframe-in-safari), that seems a similar case, but it wasn't helpful.

P.S. This is my first StackOverflow question, hoping that I've been good at writing it :) feel free to ask more about it.

EDIT: the absolutely positioned div must be at that position. Obviously it should be hidden, and this is the wanted behaviour. I can't figure out why it suddenly becomes visible after the iframe loading.

EDIT2: I've simplified the code, now the `html, body` rule is there only to cut off blank spaces around the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

First one is useless complexity.

Second issue is wrong positioning. `right` property will place your element *x* *units* from the right edge. When you give it value less than zero. It will be placed **behind** the right edge.

Here's the working fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ju4txce/).

[MDN on `position` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

[MDN on `right` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/right).

So why did your code did not work? Because of your `overflow: hidden; width: 100%;` given to almost every element you can (useless complexity, just add it where you **really** need it; also avoid giving any rule to `html` - it can be tricky). After loading wrong positioned `iframe` browser scrolled to it and *"half"* of your content was cut because of the `overflow`.

**Updated fiddle**: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7e0n6jmw/).

**Updated fiddle#2** (the best): [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bo2rzag/).

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the production environment. The div that contains the iframe should be actually behind the right edge, and should be behind even after the iframe loading. About complexity, the container div have to be at 100% width and height of the browser window.

Comment: Thank you for your useful edit. I've simplified the example, removing overflow and position properties from html and body selectors. However the problem is still there. Actually the browser scrolls to the iframe, but how this can be possible, if the iframe is cross origin?

Comment: @MarcoTodisco Changed fiddle a little bit. It is more like hotfix but it works. Link at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @MarcoTodisco And changed it once more to avoid that glitch on loading.

Comment: thanks for your updated fiddle. It works now, even if I solved in a different way (preventing the container div to be scrolled from the iframe, I'll post a fiddle later). The key actually was figuring out that page layout "broke" because the inner frame scrolled parent window. Thank you :) accepted answer

Comment: And here's the fiddle that fits my use case better: https://jsfiddle.net/xookzzxr/1/

Comment: Naruhodo, naruhodo. This one is nice solution, too!

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue with your code and that is "right: -400px;" just avoid negative sign. Swap it with "right: 400px;".